# InvalidSelectorException while passing string variable using Select_by_value function

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, exception, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I am trying to select one value by passing it in a string variable. But getting InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified.

```
    def Assignments(url,assignto,count):
           sta = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("bulk_status"))
           sta.select_by_value('Assigned')
           sta = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("bulk_assigned_individual"))
           sta.select_by_value(str(assignto))
    Assignments(UrlForIssues[1],str(teammate),1)
```

UrlForIssues - It is a list or Url
teammate - string variable
count is for something else, can ignore.

Now the issue is when I am running the program it throws exception.

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

And when I pass some string to function select_by_value(). Like:

```
select_by_value('abc')
```

It works fine, getting the error only with passing it as variable.

Set of options available.

```
<select name="bulk_assigned_individual"id="bulk_assigned_individual">
  <option value="brand-validator-queue">1 - bvq</option>
  <option value="atmakb">98 - Bharath</option>
  <option value="bvarn">98 - varun </option>
  <option value="archawla">98 - Aryan </option>
  <option value="jhiman">98 - Himanshu </option>
</select>
```

I've stored all the values in a file, and reading it in a list.

```
team = open("team.txt",'r')
teammates = team.readlines()
```

And then calling Assignments() in for loop for all options we have.

```
for teammate in teammates:
     Assignments(UrlForIssues[1],str(teammate),1)
```

Comment: What is the value of `assignto`? can you print it out before run `select_by_value`. It seems there is an invalid char in var `assignto` that makes invalid css selector.

Comment: I tried printing assignto, it's printing the correct values.

Comment: Could you share html of select tag and point out what option you want to select?

Comment: You are passing `teammate` show us how have you defined that in your code

Comment: I've edited the question and added few more line of code.. Please check

Comment: before this `sta.select_by_value(str(assignto))` put a debugger or simply print `print(assignto)` not with str and then print `print(type(assignto))` and let me know the output

Comment: print(assignto) gave this -> jhiman

print(type(assignto)) gave this output->  <class 'str'>

Comment: The only thing I don't understand here is right, when I call the function. Select_by_value('jhiman'), everything is working fine. But when passed through variable it throws exception.

Comment: Thanks for help, actually the variable which I was getting from list had NEWLINE. That messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below and confirm.

Since you are passing it as a `String` variable, below statement will return `False`:

```
print(assignto == options.get_attribute("value"))
```

So in a `for` loop check if the `assignto` value is in the options `value` and then select that option:

```
def Assignments(url,assignto,count):
    sta = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("bulk_status"))
    sta.select_by_value('Assigned')
    sta = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("bulk_assigned_individual")).options
    for opt in options:
        if assignto in options.get_attribute("value"):
            opt.click()
            break
```

Comment: Thanks for help, actually the variable which I was getting from list had NEWLINE. That messed up.

Comment: Well answer your question with working code, it might help others.